# what url to be added in IE trusted site for linqpad 5

Tags: internet-explorer, linqpad

installed linqpad5 free version on windows server 2012 R2 machine. 
every time, after running the query , a popup shows "IE not trusted site error..."

whats the url needs to be added in IE's trusted site to allow linq pad results.

Comment: You shouldn't need to add a host to trusted sites for LINQPad to work. Perhaps you have something else mis-configured in IE?

Comment: I get this too and it's a real pain.  Sometimes I do not have rights or am on a machine where IE has never run before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only one I needed to add was

```
about:security_LinqPad.exe
```

Comment: I had to uncheck the "Require server verification for all sites listed in this zone" in order to add the above then recheck it. Just in case anyone else has the same issue.

Comment: For LINQPad 6, use `about:security_LINQPad6.exe`.